# autoit - how to display files in a directory?

Tags: autoit

I'm trying to display a list of files that are located within a directory.

This is the relevant code that I have so far:

```
; Includes the GuiConstants (required for GUI function usage)
#include <GuiConstants.au3>
#include <File.au3>
#include <Array.au3>

Global $inputBox, $downloadsURL, $files

; Change to OnEvent mode
Opt('GUIOnEventMode', 1)

; GUI Creation
GuiCreate("Downloads Script", 400, 200)

; Runs the GUIExit() function if the GUI is closed
GUISetOnEvent($GUI_EVENT_CLOSE, 'GUIExit')


; Button1
GUICtrlCreateButton("Download File", -1, 60)
GUICtrlSetOnEvent(-1, 'runDownload') ; Runs function when pressed

Func runDownload()
$files = _FileListToArray("C:\Users\<user.name>\Pictures" , "*." , 1)
_ArrayDisplay($files)

EndFunc


; Shows the GUI after the function completes
GUISetState(@SW_SHOW)

; Idles the script in an infinite loop - this MUST be included when using OnEvent mode
While 1
   Sleep(500)
WEnd

; This function makes the script exit when the GUI is closed
Func GUIExit()
Exit
EndFunc
```

After clicking the button, nothing happens. the script just runs forever.... What am I missing??

On a side note... long term goal for this script is for it to execute whatever file is located within that particular directory... Would it be possible for me to pass an array value into the "Run" or "ShellExecute" functions?

Thanks for any help you may be able to provide... it is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
; Includes the GuiConstants (required for GUI function usage)
#include <GuiConstants.au3>
#include <File.au3>
#include <Array.au3>


Global $inputBox, $downloadsURL, $files


; Change to OnEvent mode
Opt('GUIOnEventMode', 1)


; GUI Creation
GUICreate("Downloads Script", 400, 200)
; Runs the GUIExit() function if the GUI is closed
GUISetOnEvent($GUI_EVENT_CLOSE, 'GUIExit')

; Button1
GUICtrlCreateButton("Download File", 0, 60)
GUICtrlSetOnEvent(-1, 'runDownload') ; Runs function when pressed

; Shows the GUI after the function completes
GUISetState(@SW_SHOW)


; Idles the script in an infinite loop - this MUST be included when using OnEvent mode
While 1
    Sleep(500)
WEnd

Func runDownload()
    $files = _FileListToArray(@UserProfileDir & "\Pictures", "*.*", 1)
    _ArrayDisplay($files)
EndFunc   ;==>runDownload

; This function makes the script exit when the GUI is closed
Func GUIExit()
    Exit
EndFunc   ;==>GUIExit
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought it obvious by comparing the two.  They had `"*."`, it requires `"*.*"`.  And I just made it universally usable by using the users profile directory macro.